# GNU parallel errors on —onall

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sh, gnu-parallel

I am trying to send a bash function over ssh and execute it on all remote hosts. Something like this:

```
f() { echo $1; }
parallel -—onall -S host1,host2 “$(typeset -f f); f” ::: foo
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/bash: \{\ : command not found
/bin/bash: \ \ \ \ echo\ \$1: command not found
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/bash: \{\ : command not found
/bin/bash: \ \ \ \ echo\ \$1: command not found
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This entire snippet works perfectly if I remove —-onall and run the function on one host only:

```
parallel -S host1,host2 “$(typeset -f f); f” ::: foo
```

Gives the output: `foo`

Any insights as to what might be wrong would help :-). I am using version 20180422.

Comment: You're using some funny quotes or smart quotes as some windows user calls it. Also afaik you need to export functions to work over ssh but not sure.

Comment: I don’t think either quoting or export is the problem here since parallel works well over ssh without specifying —onall.

export is only needed if you are calling the function inside parallel directly. “$(typeset -f f); f” is first evaluated by bash to: “f() { echo $1”}; f” before running parallel over it.

Comment: You can always verify your script via https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Just did. The only warning it throws is  “f appears to be unused”. Tried export as well, just to be on the safe side. Didn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `env_parallel`:

```
f() { echo foo; echo "$@"; }
env_parallel -S host1,host2 --onall f ::: a b c
```

If you get:

```
bash: /usr/bin/perl: Argument list too long
env_parallel: Error: Your environment is too big.
env_parallel: Error: You can try 3 different approaches:
env_parallel: Error: 1. Run 'env_parallel --session' before you set
env_parallel: Error:    variables or define functions.
env_parallel: Error: 2. Use --env and only mention the names to copy.
env_parallel: Error: 3. Try running this in a clean environment once:
env_parallel: Error:      env_parallel --record-env
env_parallel: Error:    And then use '--env _'
env_parallel: Error: For details see: man env_parallel
```

Then try these 3 different approaches:

```
unset f
env_parallel --session
f() { echo foo; echo "$@"; }
env_parallel -S host1,host2 --onall f ::: a b c
```

or:

```
f() { echo foo; echo "$@"; }
env_parallel --env f -S host1,host2 --onall f ::: a b c
```

or:

```
unset f
env_parallel --record-env
f() { echo foo; echo "$@"; }
env_parallel --env _ -S host1,host2 --onall f ::: a b c
```

For details see: `man env_parallel`

Or upgrade to 20180922:

```
parallel-20180922 --onall -S host1,host2 "$(typeset -f f); f" ::: a b c
```

Comment: I did not want to use env_parallel since my environment was extremely large. Updating parallel fixed it. Thanks!